# How to register components in Aframe using Nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, aframe

I'm trying to create a VR scene using Aframe, and I want to register a custom Aframe component, with click events, as in the example.

I tried this:

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next';

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  Scene,
  Box,
  Sky,
  Entity,
  Assets
} from '@belivvr/aframe-react';

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const [rendered, setRendered] = useState<boolean>(false);


  function register() {
    AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
      events: {
        click: function (evt: any) {
          console.log('This entity was clicked!');
        }
      }
    });
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    setRendered(true);
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      require('aframe');
      register();
    }
  }, [setRendered]);

  if (!rendered) {
    return <>loading</>;
  }

  return (
    <Scene>
      <Assets>
        <img id="sky" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/c52283d6-3489-44e4-b56b-43550d1bc76c%2F1.jpg?v=1564408735128" alt="sky" />
        <img id="hotspot" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/c52283d6-3489-44e4-b56b-43550d1bc76c%2Fhotspot.png?v=1564471993959" />
      </Assets>
      <Box
        foo
        position={{ x: -1, y: 0.5, z: -3 }}
        rotation={{ x: 0, y: 45, z: 0 }}
        color="#4CC3D9"
      />
      <Entity>
        <Sky className="sky" src="#sky" rotation={{ x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }} />
      </Entity>

    </Scene>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

But I receive the following error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: The component `foo` has been already registered. Check that you are not loading two versions of the same component or two different components of the same name.
```

Does anyone have any idea how to work properly with Aframe and NextJs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem was related to React's StrictMode, just remove it and it worked as it should.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if component exists

```
function register() {
    if (AFRAME.components['foo']) return;

    AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
      events: {
        click: function (evt: any) {
          console.log('This entity was clicked!');
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

If you are using `nextjs` you can move this function to another file and import it using `next/dynamic`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new module with your component defined within:

```
// foo.js
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
  init: function() {
    console.log("FOO INIT!");
  }
});
```

And import it after `a-frame`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setRendered(true);
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    require('aframe');
    require('foo');
  }
}, [setRendered]);
```

Keep in mind, that the component has to be registered before the scene is attached to the DOM ([docs](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html)), but after requiring `a-frame`